# Reinstalling Ubuntu While Keeping Files and Programs

Tags: xorg, reinstall

[image: Ubuntu installer]
After messing up my Xorg I decided to do a reinstall using the installation DVD (I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu) since user files aren't affected. I'm not even able to use the recovery mode, I booted by holding down the shift button. I do not get the login screen, the screen just flashes endlessly and I can't access terminal.
I want to know more about this reinstallation option. Will the Xorg be restored to it's default state and are my install software packages kept?

Answer (score 0):

A reinstallation will do just that. But it will also wipe any files on that partition. So you will want to back up your data first.

1. Have a medium to reinstall Ubuntu (Usb key or cd) and create said medium.
2. Have a back up medium, for example a usb key or an external usb hd.
3. Boot into Ubuntu.
4. Open the file browser, mount your hard-drive (the one all your stuff is in) in live mode and backup to your backup medium.
5. Reinstall ubuntu